# oracle query to extract data dictionary information, including primary key table and column that this foreign key is pointing to

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, data-dictionary

I need to create a query in Oracle 10g for a data dictionary that extracts the following information for all the tables in a given schema:

1. Table name
2. Column name
3. “P” if the column is a primary key
4. If this column is referenced in a foreign key, the Table name +
       ‘.’ + column name of the primary key in another table that this 
       foreign key is pointing to.
5. Column data type

For now I am just trying to get this to work for a single table in a given schema. 
I have a query that extracts everything correctly except for item 4.  For item 4, I am returning the foreign key the row is pointing to (primary key table name and column in other table) in *every* row, not just the row that has the foreign key.

I don’t have permission to write to any schema so I can’t create working tables or use a stored procedure.  I’ve worked on this so long I am starting to wonder if it is possible to extract this information in a single query.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
     t.table_name,
     c.column_name,
     (SELECT con.constraint_type
        FROM all_constraints con, all_cons_columns cols
       WHERE     con.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
             AND con.owner = cols.owner
             AND t.table_name = cols.table_name
             AND c.column_name = cols.column_name
             AND con.constraint_type = 'P'      --  AND status = 'enabled'
                                          )
        AS pk_constraint,
     (SELECT (SELECT conc.table_name || '.' || conc.column_name
                FROM all_cons_columns conc
               WHERE conc.owner = con.owner
                     AND constraint_name = con.r_constraint_name)
                fk_ref
        FROM all_constraints con, all_cons_columns col
       WHERE     con.owner = col.owner
             AND con.table_name = t.table_name
             AND con.constraint_name = col.constraint_name
             AND con.constraint_type = 'R')
        AS fk_constraint,
     c.data_type,
     d.comments
FROM all_tables t, all_tab_columns c, all_col_comments d
WHERE     t.table_name = c.table_name
     AND t.owner = c.owner
     AND t.table_name = d.table_name
     AND t.owner = d.owner
     AND t.owner = %MY_SCHEMA_NAME%
     AND t.table_name = %MY_TABLE_NAME%
ORDER BY t.table_name, c.column_name;
```

This is what should be returned (sample data – assuming that CustomerAddress.State contains a code that references table State containing list of state codes that has a primary key State.StateCode):

- CustomerAddress AddressID  P NULL NUMBER
- CustomerAddress  StreetAddress  NULL NULL VARCHAR(2)
- CustomerAddress State  NULL State.StateCode CHAR

This is what my query actually returns.  You can see that State.StateCode is repeated in every row. It should only appear in the last row.

- CustomerAddress AddressID  P State.StateCode NUMBER
- CustomerAddress  StreetAddress  NULL State.StateCode  VARCHAR(2)
- CustomerAddress State  NULL State.StateCode CHAR

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the StackExchange website has the answer you are looking for at [this link.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11047/how-to-retrieve-foreign-key-constraints-data)

The answer based on Frosty Code does about what you need it to and with a little bit of experimentation you'll get the results you want.